# Hosting a text file that will be used to implement high scores for a game

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in unity 5 that I would like to implement a high score system for in which all users have a chance at having the high score among all players. My question is, is there a way for me to just have a text file hosted somewhere so that I do not have to setup a server for this? I know usually a database would be most beneficial for a high traffic situation but for right now the high scores will literally only keep track of 3 scores at a time. 1st, 2nd, and 3rd place.

I have looked into the textupload.com api and the pastebin.com api and I am not really sure they will do what I am hoping while also not allowing users to not edit things themselves.

I just want to host this file on the internet somewhere so my app can read from it to compare the local player's scores to the high scores and then append the file if score changes must be made.

Comment: Yes it seems very possible. This question could also benefit being posted here on the Unity Forum too http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/516268/is-it-possible-to-pull-the-file-name-from-a-www-ge.html

Comment: you can use [Parse](http://parse.com) for hosting database.

Comment: it is inconceivable you would do this by hand, in this day and age.  note that **game center, and the equivalent google service, are utterly free**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There several services for leaderbords many of them with free plans and support for Unity3D and other platforms:

[Playtomic](http://playtomic.org)

[Parse](https://www.parse.com)

[Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/)

[App42 Cloud API Services](http://api.shephertz.com/)

Or more generic solutions like: [Microsoft Azure Mobile Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/)